# .NET Core installation on Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I have a problem with .NET Core installation on Mac OS X (El Capitan 10.11). Generally, I did everything as [MS documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos) said but when I'm trying to test the installation (dotnet new) I get an error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'Crypto' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'CryptoInitializer' threw an exception. --->
>   System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.Native': The specified module could not
>   be found.

I was trying to deploy .NET core through manual process, i.e. downloaded all the packages from Git, install mandatory libraries (like openssl) via Homebrew and start compiling. Coreclr has compiled well, but corefx gives errors resembling to what I received with automatic installation:

> In file included from
>   /usr/local/git/corefx/src/Native/Unix/System.Security.Cryptography.Native/pal_ecdsa.cpp:5:
>   /usr/local/git/corefx/src/Native/Unix/System.Security.Cryptography.Native/pal_ecdsa.h:7:10:
>   fatal error: 'openssl/ecdsa.h' file not found
>
> ## include
>
> ```
>      ^ make[2]: *** [System.Security.Cryptography.Native/CMakeFiles/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dir/pal_bignum.cpp.o]
> ```
>
> Error 1

I looked through the interned for possible solution with no luck. I cannot get one thing... if openssl lib is deprecated, why in the world MS keeps using it, as it obviously causes a lot of pain in well known place.
Has anybody managed to run .NET core on Mac, having the issue I described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I decided to reinstall everything from scratch. I have deleted git repo with dotnetfx source, cleaned out 'lib' and 'opt' folders (from 'openssl'), deleted Cellar folder (where 'openssl' reside). Once I did all this, I've started a new installation and followed instructions published on the [official resource](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos) This time it all been deployed and works like a charm.